# Github Private Repo connection issue on cPanel

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, namecheap

How can I solve the issue in order to add a github private repository on namecheap cpanel shared hosting

> ERROR: You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cPanel haven't supported the RSA SHA-2 fingerprint SSH required by GitHub yet so its best you use the ECDSA ssh type to connect to the private repository. Firstly, delete the previous rsa key generated, then follow the process below:

**1. Generate An SSH Key**

> ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "username@example"

In this example, "**username**" represents the cPanel account username and "**example**" represents the domain name.

After you run this command, the system will prompt you to enter a passphrase.

**Do not enter a passphrase.**

Press Enter to continue.

**2. Verify That You Generated The Ssh Key Correctly**

To confirm that the key exists and is in the correct location, run the following command:

> cat ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub

**3. Register Your SSH Key With The Private Repository Host**

For information about how to register your SSH key with another private repository host (Bitbucket, GitLab, etc), consult that host's website or documentation.

Some repository hosts, such as Bitbucket, do not allow you to configure write access for your access keys.

To register an SSH key with GitHub, perform the following steps:

1. Log in to your GitHub account.
2. Navigate to your private repository.
3. In the top right corner of the page, click **Settings**. A new page will appear.
4. In the left side menu, click **Deploy** keys. A new page will appear.
5. In the top right corner of the page, click **Add deploy key**. A new page will appear.
6. Enter your SSH key data:
7. In the Title text box, enter a display name for the key.
8. In the Key text box, paste the entire SSH key. If you want to push code from your cPanel account to your GitHub account, select the **"Allow write access" checkbox**. Do note that if you do not select this checkbox, you can only deploy changes from your GitHub repository to the cPanel-hosted repository.
9. Click **Add key**.

**4. Test Out The SSH Key**

To test your SSH key, run the following command.

> ssh -T git@example.com

where example.com represents the private repository's host - e.g ssh -T git@github.com.

**5. Clone The Private Repo**

Go to the Git Version Control in your cPanel and clone your repository there.

Reference: - https://dashboard.webhostingmagic.com/knowledgebase/242/How-To-Clone-A-Private-Github-Repo-To-A-cPanel-Server.html